# Long Bond & Interest Rate Futures Hedge - is it carry negative?

Tags: fixed-income, futures, hedging, treasury

The situation is the following :

- A bank treasury book, finances its cash bond liquidity portfolio at Euribor 3m flat.
- The Euribor curve is deeply inverted.
- The bank invests in bonds with a positive spread over the swap curve, but the bonds' yield is below the 3M Euribor it pays to purchase them (curve is inverted).
- To hedge IR risk and lock in a spread over swaps, bank sells Euribor futures strips to hedge bond purchases.

Assuming no change in rates over a time period T, is the overall **carry** on this position positive or negative ? What are the factors that determine it ?

Answer (score 2):

The position you describe is a long basis position--Long Bond, Short Future.

Carry is the difference between Coupon and Financing.

$$Carry = Coupon - Financing$$

As you mentioned, the yield is less then 3M Euribor that is being used to finance the position implies that you are earning less in interest than the cost to finance the position, therefore the Carry is Negative.

Let's take an example:  Say 3M Euribor is 6% and 1Yr Euribor is 4%.  If you are financing a 1Yr 4% annual coupon, yielding 4%, Par bond for 3 Months, the interest (Coupon) earned would be 1% in 3 Months.  Since you are funding the position with 3M Euribor for 3 Months, the financing would be 6% x 90/360 = 1.5%.

$$Carry = (0.01)(100) - (0.015)(100) = (-0.005)(100) = -0.5$$

This represents a loss for a long basis position, if basis stays the same.

Comment: Let's expand the definition of "carry return" for anything that has to do with ONLY the passage of time, not any market price moves. 

This includes the roll-down of the upward sloping futures price curve, with the passage of time. 

Roll-up the downward yield curve for the long bond. 

Also assume the case when the coupon of the bond purchased is above the 3M Euribor, thus making the bond trade above par. 

What happens after 3 months of holding this position, if yields do not move?

Comment: The **immediate** carry is negative, but over the life of the bond the funding rate is forecast to fall below the coupon, so that that latter half of the bond has positive carry. In fact, becuase you investing in a bond yielding 3M + 20bps and you are funding it at 3M + 0 you will earn net profit of 20bps as measured over the life. But as stated in accrual terms this is a loss at start and gain at the end.

Comment: Additionally if the assumption is that the curve rates are realised, your mention of Interest Rate Futures hedges is a red herring to the calculation. With that assumption the futures prices will not move so they are irrelevant (unless you want to incorporate futures convexity adjustements - which you really dont want to do for this analysis)

Comment: What if I had used a par-par payer IRS, to hedge, instead of Euribor futures strips?

That has me receive 3M Euribor, which offsets the 3M Euribor I have to pay to finance the bond. 
And has me pay fixed, at a rate that is below the yield of the bond I invested in.

How does the carry evolve in this situation, and if different from the IR futures case, why? 

Thank you for the answers.